# How can I get file extension by file name from codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I uploaded users profile photos with `gif`, `jpg` and `png` extension using codeigniter, now I want to display user photo in website after login, from `<img>` tag I am not able to display all type of images.

using code:

```
<img src="assets/images/<?php echo $result->imgid; ?>.png" />
```

so, my plan is getting file extension with help of file name from controller, then pass that string to view file. but how can search file and how can i get full file name from directory? or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob - like so:

```
$fileName = glob('assets/images/'.$result->imgid.'.*');
```

This should return an array of file names that match the pattern.

Comment: will it return with extension? because i want to pass this to view file.

Comment: Yes - it will return the extension

Comment: it returns complete path name with extension as string then how can i get only image name and extension. i think we need `str_split`.

Comment: $matchingFileName = basename(preg_grep('#/'.$result->imgid.'\.#', $fileName));

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get file extension.

```
echo $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

It will return you the file extension

Comment: `$ext` returns null value, my `$filename` is 1001, this image present in my directory, is need to mention complete path name?

Comment: variable is 1001 contains in filename, `pathinfo('1001', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` like that

Comment: i have only file name without extension, i do not know what type of file user uploaded, so i have to find the extension. `$filepath = 'assets/images/profile-photos/'.$imgid;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the filename then why do you need to analyse it to retrieve the extension? Cant you just do:

```
<img src="assets/images/<?php echo $filename; ?>" />
```

As this should contain the filename with appropriate extension

From your comment maybe this variable contains path info. In which case this should work.

```
<img src="assets/images/<?php echo basename($filename); ?>" />
```

The `basename()` function will retrieve just file name and extension from a full file path. Of course this would also work if you had a full path

```
<img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>" />
```

Comment: Echo out `$filename` and see what it looks like. In case it contains path information I have updated my answer..